# One dimensional array but multiple string

Tags: arrays, c, input

I want to make a multiple string of array but with just a one dimensional array, Is it possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name1[10];
    char name2[10];
    
    printf("Enter name1: ");
    scanf("%s", name1);
    
    printf("Enter name2: ");
    scanf("%s", name2);
    
    printf("\n%s", name1);
    printf("\n%s", name2);

    return 0;
}
```

I just started to learn array and I wanted to try to get multiple input from user and display only specific of the elements.
This is one of the code I tried before but it does not run.

```
int main()
{
    char *name[10];

    int i = 1, input;
    printf("How many days a week: "); 
    scanf("%d", &input);
    
    do{
        printf("enter day %d: ", i);
        scanf("%s", name[i]);
        i++;
    }while(i < input);
    
    //output wanted
    printf("\n%s", name[0]);
    printf("\n%s", name[4]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: For me it is unclear what you want to reach. Please try to rephrase. Also please add sample input and desired output.

Comment: Sorry for that, I just edit the post. The final output that I wanted is to display the chosen array from the user input only.

Comment: Make an Array of strings? or a 2Dimensional Char Array should do the Trick

Comment: @eccentriclearner: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

A rather peculiar demand, but it could be achieved like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char names[256];
    
    printf("Enter name1: ");
    scanf("%s", names);
    
    printf("Enter name2: ");
    scanf("%s", names + strlen(names) + 1);
    
    printf("\n%s", names);
    printf("\n%s", names + strlen(names) + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

This way, the strings are concatenated in the array and separated by the terminating 0.

Comment: The OP is confused and doesn't know the proper way... and this isn't it for sure.

Comment: So it would seem. However for the lack of information about what they want to achieve, I merely answered the question.

Comment: The purpose of this site isn't to mislead people by blindly follow a specification - that's bad engineering. Good engineering = question the specification, make sure it's making sense _before_ writing a single line of code.

Comment: Point taken. And you are right. While there are valid use cases for concatenating strings in a single buffer (i.e. for sending them over a socket), this question very likely is not among them.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very unclear, but it sounds to me that you do not want a one-dimensional array, but rather a two-dimensional array (despite your question explicitly stating the opposite).

I suggest that you change `char *name[10];` to `char name[10][10];` Also, you may want to change the variable name of the 2D-array `name` to `names`, because that name is misleading, as it implies that it contains only a single string.

Also, you must start the loop counter `i` at `0`, not `1`, as array indexes are zero-based in C.

After making these changes, your program should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char names[10][10];

    int i = 0, input;
    printf("How many days a week: "); 
    scanf("%d", &input);
    
    do{
        printf("Enter day %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", names[i]);
        i++;
    }while(i < input);
    
    //output wanted
    printf("The first day is: %s\n", names[0]);
    printf("The fifth day is: %s\n", names[4]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
How many days a week: 7
Enter day 1: Monday
Enter day 2: Tuesday
Enter day 3: Wednesday
Enter day 4: Thursday
Enter day 5: Friday
Enter day 6: Saturday
Enter day 7: Sunday
The first day is: Monday
The fifth day is: Friday
```

Note that the program will write to the array out of bounds if the user enters an integer larger than `10` or if any of the days has a length larger than `9` (`10` including the terminating null character).

Also, your program would have a cleaner structure if you used a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop, as it reduces the [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope) of the loop counter.

Another issue is that the program will misbehave if the user does not enter a number. Instead, it should check if the function `scanf` succeeded, and to print an error message if it did not.

Therefore, it would be better to write it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_DAYS 10

//MAX_DAY_LENGTH_FORMAT_STRING, which is used by scanf,
//should always be set to one less than MAX_DAY_LENGTH,
//because the latter also needs room for the terminating
//null character
#define MAX_DAY_LENGTH 10
#define MAX_DAY_LENGTH_FORMAT_STRING "%9s"

int main( void )
{
    char names[MAX_DAYS][MAX_DAY_LENGTH];
    int num_days;

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "How many days a week: " );

    //attempt to read input
    if ( scanf( "%d", &num_days ) != 1 )
    {
        printf( "Input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //verify that input is in desired range
    if ( ! ( 1 <= num_days && num_days <= 10 ) )
    {
        printf( "Input out of range!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_days; i++ )
    {
        int num_read;

        //prompt user for input
        printf( "Enter day %d: ", i+1 );

        //attempt to read input
        if ( scanf( MAX_DAY_LENGTH_FORMAT_STRING "%n", names[i], &num_read ) != 1 )
        {
            printf( "input error!" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //check whether input was small enough to fit in buffer
        if ( num_read == MAX_DAY_LENGTH && getchar() != '\n' )
        {
            printf( "Input too long to fit in buffer!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    
    //print input back to user
    printf("The first day is: %s\n", names[0]);
    printf("The fifth day is: %s\n", names[4]);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The program will now perform proper input validation instead of causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) on bad input:

```
How many days a week: abc
Input error!
```

```
How many days a week: 11
Input out of range!
```

```
How many days a week: 7
Enter day 1: Monday
Enter day 2: Tuesday
Enter day 3: Wednesdaay
Input too long to fit in buffer!
```

Comment: Thanks, I now understand the reason why we need the two dimensional array and the naming importance

Comment: @eccentriclearner 2D arrays are rather clunky when dealing with an array of strings, because you force every string to have the same max length, 10 in this case. An array of pointers means that each string can be given an individual length, which is the normal use.

Comment: @Lundin: When using dynamic memory allocation, a bit of space is wasted, too (e.g. 16-byte alignment, overhead). Also, using fixed-length arrays is simpler. Therefore, it depends on the use-case which solution is better. OP seems to be looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code does not *work* is the array of pointers `char *name[10];` is uninitialized so you pass an invalid address `name[i]` to `scanf()`.

You can initialize the array explicitly this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name0[20], name1[20], name2[20], name3[20], name4[20];
    char name5[20], name6[20], name7[20], name8[20], name9[20];
    char *name[10] = { name0, name1, name2, name3, name4,
                       name5, name6, name7, name8, name9 };
    int i, input;
    printf("How many days a week: "); 
    if (scanf("%d", &input) != 1 || input < 1 || input > 10) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        printf("enter day %d: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%19s", name[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    //output wanted
    printf("%s\n", name[0]);
    if (input > 4)
        printf("%s\n", name[4]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Alternately, you can use a 2D array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[10][20];
    int i, input;
    printf("How many days a week: "); 
    if (scanf("%d", &input) != 1 || input < 1 || input > 10) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        printf("enter day %d: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%19s", name[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    //output wanted
    printf("%s\n", name[0]);
    if (input > 4)
        printf("%s\n", name[4]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this beginner string handling FAQ: [Common string handling pitfalls in C programming](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284849). Yours is FAQ #3 - you try to store data using a pointer which isn't pointing at a valid memory location.

`char *name[10];` is correct as far as it can be used for the `name[i]` syntax to access a string. However, it is just an array of pointers which don't point to allocated data yet. You need to set these pointers to point somewhere before using them.

One way to do so:

```
char name1[100];
char name2[100];
char* name[10] = {name1, name2};
...
scanf("%s", name[i]); // now this is fine
```

Alternatively using dynamic allocation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...

char* name[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  name[i] = malloc(100);
  if(name[i]==NULL) { /* handle error */ return 0; }
}
...
scanf("%s", name[i]); // now this is fine
...
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) // cleanup
{
  free(name[i]);
}
```

The advantage of dynamic allocation is that we can `realloc` a string later in runtime to change the string length.